# Can az image copy only copy the image without also taking a snapshot?

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

Whenever I use the az image copy command, it works great, but it creates snapshots for each image I'm copying in the source resource group. I have to go back and delete these later.

Is there a way to have only the image itself copied without a snapshot also being created?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You may use the below command to copy the image between two resource groups

```
az image copy --source-object-name
          --source-resource-group
          --target-location
          --target-resource-group
          --cleanup
```

- In the above command, the "--clean up" flag  will help you
  in deleting the snapshots & the transient resource group that were
  created while copying the image between source & destination resource
  groups.

Here is the reference document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/image?view=azure-cli-latest.

Comment: @Williams76 - If the answer provided was helpful ? If so could you please accept the answer as a  solution . This could help other community users who have similar query in the future